# Regex to remove all special characters except periods

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I need help with creating a regex that removes all special characters, including commas, but not periods. What I have tried to do is escape all the characters, symbols and punctuation I do not want. It is not working as intended.

```
replace("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:.!><~@#\$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+".toRegex(), "")
```

I removed the period and tested that too. It did not work.

```
replace("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:!><~@#\$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+".toRegex(), "")
```

For example, lets take the String "if {cat.is} in a hat, then I eat green eggs and ham!".

I want the result

`if {cat.is} in a hat then I eat green eggs and ham` (comma and exclamation symbol removed)

Note: I want to keep brackets, although braces are OK to omit.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I am using Kotlin. Let me add that to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
"""[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^.]]+""".toRegex()
```

The `[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^.]]+` pattern matches one or more (`+`) punctuation proper (`\p{P}`) or symbol (`\p{S}`) chars other than dots (`&&[^.]`, using character class subtraction).

See a [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/JMCKW43621):

```
println("a-b)h.".replace("""[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^.]]+""".toRegex(), ""))
// => abh.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this with "if {cat.is} in a hat, then I eat green eggs and ham!".replace("""[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^.]]+""".toRegex(), ""). I was expecting that the comma and the ! will be removed, but this was not the case.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder See [this Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/HVR69937). The `if {cat.is} in a hat, then I eat green eggs and ham!` turns into `if cat.is in a hat then I eat green eggs and ham`.